# PHP Classes - Better alternative to $this->base->class->method

Tags: php, oop, base-class

At the moment, I have a main class `Base` that loads all other controllers and models and then each class that is loaded by `Base` has a similar structure:

```
class SomeClass {

    private $base;

    function __construct(&$base) {
        $this->base = $base;
    }

    function SomeMethod() { }

}
```

Then another class would have to use:

```
class AnotherClass {

    private $base;

    function __construct(&$base) {
        $this->base = $base;

        $this->base->SomeClass->SomeMethod();
    }

}
```

Is there a better way of accessing these other classes?

Comment: Have you looked at class SomeClass extends BaseClass ?

Comment: They don't extend the functionality of the BaseClass. They are loaded by it then called by the BaseClass for certain purposes.

E.g. the BaseClass might call DatabaseClass and AuthenticationClass then a controll SomeController which would use AuthenticationClass and DatabaseClass.

Comment: sorry, looks like I didn't correctly understand your original question, please disregard my former comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps someMethod() could be static:

```
class SomeClass {

    private $base;

    function __construct(&$base) {
        $this->base = $base;
    }

    public static function SomeMethod() { }

}
```

And then just:

```
class AnotherClass {

    private $base;

    function __construct(&$base) {
        $this->base = $base;

        SomeClass::SomeMethod();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This won't work in every situation that I have to use the classes but will do for several.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `Base` is an implementation of the [Front Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern). The Front Controller is a special case of a [Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern), which does exactly what you're doing. It essentially allows `SomeClass` and `AnotherClass` to be developed and maintained separately with fewer dependencies.

However, rather than directly accessing the classes from the `Base` class, it might be best to have `SomeClass` and `AnotherClass` register themselves with the `Base` class, and expose getter methods that the other objects call:

```
class Base {
    protected $_authenticator;

    public function setAuthenticator(Authenticator $auth) {
        $this->_authenticator = $auth;
    }

    public function getAuthenticator() {
        return $this->_authenticator;
    }
}

class Authenticator {
    protected $_base;

    public function __construct(Base $base) {
        $this->_base = $base;
        $this->_base->setAuthenticator($this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your notes on this. I'll have a go at implementing this into my project.